# Where is mysqld.sock?

Tags: server, mysql

I am missing mysqld.sock in Ubuntu Server 12.04. Neither locate nor even

```
apt-file search mysqld.sock (ran apt-file update before)
```

can find it. Where is it?

Answer (score 2):

Solved:
mysqld.sock is created when mysqld starts / while it is running (it's a socket!).